# How To make Label like below image in swift

Tags: swift

I have working on chatting app and i have try to make label like bellow image but i can't done anyone can help me.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at https://www.innofied.com/creating-old-style-message-bubble-swift/

Comment: try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kR9cf_K_9Tk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode go to your assets, select your bubble image and click on `show slicing`.

Slicing enable your image to stretch with the given slices without deforming.

Comment: Thanks, brother it's really outstanding

Answer (score -1):

It is complicated to draw this form using CoreGraphics. I have achieved this result which is not perfect.You can use this code in "drawRect" method, and after you have to draw (or to override the layout) the text.

```
func drawCanvas1(frame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 100)) {
    //// General Declarations
    // This non-generic function dramatically improves compilation times of complex expressions.
    func fastFloor(_ x: CGFloat) -> CGFloat { return floor(x) }

    //// Rectangle Drawing
    let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: frame.minX + fastFloor(frame.width * 0.25000 + 0.5), y: frame.minY + fastFloor(frame.height * 0.00000 + 0.5), width: fastFloor(frame.width * 1.00000 + 0.5) - fastFloor(frame.width * 0.25000 + 0.5), height: fastFloor(frame.height * 1.00000 + 0.5) - fastFloor(frame.height * 0.00000 + 0.5)), cornerRadius: 10)
    UIColor.gray.setFill()
    rectanglePath.fill()


    //// Bezier 3 Drawing
    let bezier3Path = UIBezierPath()
    bezier3Path.move(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.5, y: frame.minY + 85.5))
    bezier3Path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 30.5, y: frame.minY + 64.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.5, y: frame.minY + 85.5), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 30.5, y: frame.minY + 85.5))
    bezier3Path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 43.5, y: frame.minY + 99.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 30.5, y: frame.minY + 43.5), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 43.5, y: frame.minY + 99.5))
    bezier3Path.move(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.59, y: frame.minY + 85.5))
    bezier3Path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 43.5, y: frame.minY + 99.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX - 0.43, y: frame.minY + 86.43), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 6.72, y: frame.minY + 99.5))
    UIColor.gray.setFill()
    bezier3Path.fill()
    UIColor.gray.setStroke()
    bezier3Path.lineWidth = 1
    bezier3Path.lineCapStyle = .round
    bezier3Path.lineJoinStyle = .round
    bezier3Path.stroke()
}
```

[image: Result]

I recommend you to create an image in Illustrator or some other program with this form and to use it as background.